# OOP PHP - get's no value in variables

Tags: php, oop

I'm kinda confused, I'm new to OOP PHP, so can't stop my function get empty values.

I have an index.php file where I have:

```
<?php   
require_once('../../includes/functions.php'); 
require_once('../../includes/database.php');
require_once('../../includes/user.php'); 


$user = new User();
$user->username = 'test';
$user->password = '1234';
$user->firstname = 'test1';
$user->lastname = 'test2';

User::create();

// $user->traceStatement();


?>
```

I have a User class that extends Databaseobject class:
user.php:

```
<?php 
require_once('database.php');

class User extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $tableName = 'users';
    protected static $tableID = 'id';

    public $id;
    public $username;   
    public $password;   
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;

    public function traceStatement() {
        echo $this->username;   
        echo $this->password;   
        echo $this->firstname;  
        echo $this->lastname;                                   
    }


}

?>
```

and here's a snippet of create function from DatabaseObject class:

```
public function create() {
    global $database;
    $calledClass = get_called_class();
    $class = new $calledClass;      
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$calledClass::$tableName." (username, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($class->username)."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($class->password)."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($class->firstname)."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($class->lastname);
    $sql .= "')";   
    if($database->query($sql)) {
        $cass->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand the idea is that

on my index.php file i'm declaring varibales of User class, these info are sent to user.php and I'm also calling create() function from databaseobject class through User:: class, and my info inside variables will be sent to create function.

in the database I'm getting blank fields.

I tried to hardcode the variables inside my user.php - and everything work (first I thought I wasn't getting data from user.php).

When it worked I thought maybe I'm not gettind data from index.php to user.php but it turned out that when I wrote function traceStatement() - I got back the data in index.php file...

So maybe someone here know what's my problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you not getting any errors? It doesn't look like `create()` is a static function.

Comment: Overall it is better to use a getter/setter function, instead of accessing the properties directly. Just a small note, you're on the good way!

Comment: The create function you call will always create a new user. A new user has empty values, that's why it is entered empty into the database. From what I see in the code you can not go around that.

Comment: Looks like bad design... Why is the `create` function static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than`User::create();`, you should use `$user->create()`.

And your `create()` method should change to: (**$this** is very important in the OOP world)

```
public function create() {
    global $database;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".static::$tableName." (username, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($this->username)."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($this->password)."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($this->firstname)."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escapeValue($this->lastname);
    $sql .= "')";   
    if($database->query($sql)) {
        $this->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: I guess in this case I should move create function to User.php file and I won't be able to call it from DatabaseObject class... Am I right?

Comment: @Mikey If you want to call it from DatabaseObject class, you should pass the $user to `create()` rather than create a new object.

Comment: in case of self::$tablename this function is addressing this class itself, but I'm calling this function from a subclass

Comment: You can do something like `$user->getTableName()`

Comment: I want to call create() that's inside DatabaseObject from User, that's why I'm facing problem with self and $this.. maybe I'm not using static function or public non-static functions correctly, maybe you can offer my any workaround?

Comment: begin from php5.3, you can use the feather `Late Static Bindings`

Comment: I'll upload my code somewhere... could you just take a look at it and correct so it works and I'll check them, I'll understand better what you are telling me when I see the code.

Comment: yeah it did.. Thank alot XDAZZZZZZZZZZZZ :))) so you are using Late Static Binding, and isn't the function get_called_class() part of it?

I understood that in my example I was creating a new object that that was where I was loosing my DATA - am I right?

Answer (score 2):

DataBaseObject.create(0 function contains:
$class = new $calledClass;

This will create a new User object, which hasn't been initialized.
==> empty values.

In index.php, you should call:

```
$user->create();
```

(instead of User::create() ==> static)

In the databaseObject, you can just use $this->tableName, .. instead of all the $calledClass stuff.
I don't see why you want this to be static.

Comment: +1: That's the point I see as well why empty values come in there.

Comment: you know, I'm using calledClass because DatabaseObject is extended by project.php class, user.php class, and with get_called_class() I can let the function determine from where I'm calling it, in order to put relevant table name. When I do $this function addresses DatabaseObject and not User class.. so.. maybe you can advice me any workaround??? I'd apriciate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're calling the `create()` method from a static context. If you want the properties to be available in the method, you need to call it like this: `$User->create()`.